# Own simple template system in vim - include file

Tags: vim, include, skeleton-code

I've read [vim-wiki](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Use_eval_to_create_dynamic_templates) about dynamic templates and I want similar, simple "template-system". I've created a function:

```
function! Read_template(file)
    execute '0r /home/zsolt/.vim/skeletons/'.a:file
    %substitute#\[:EVAL:\]\(.\{-\}\)\[:END:\]#\=eval(submatch(1))#ge
    %substitute#\[:READ:\]\(.\{-\}\)\[:END:\]#??????#ge
endfunction
```

I want to include a file from a template. The `EVAL` works well but how can I solve the `READ` function? It isn't important to eval the included file.

An example:

`main.tex`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
....
```

`exam.tex`:

```
% Created [:EVAL:]strftime('%Y. %B. %d.')[:END:]
[:READ:]/path/of/main/main.tex[:READ:]
```

I exec `Read_template("exam.tex")` and want that `exam.tex` includes `main.tex`.

How can I do this?

Comment: Is your goal to insert the entire `main.tex` into `exam.tex` or just to add the line `\input /path/of/main/main.tex` into `exam.tex`?

Comment: I want include, not TeX-`\input`.

Comment: In that case, I do not have anything to add to the answers you have already received.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll need to read the file and insert its contents. As you cannot use `:read` (it will read entire lines and cannot be called from within a substitution), you have to use the lower-level `readfile()` Vimscript function, like this:

```
%substitute#\[:READ:\]\(.\{-\}\)\[:END:\]#\=join(readfile(submatch(1)),"\n")/#ge
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to parse each line imported and apply what needs be :
- expression substitution
- inclusion of other templates, etc. (which will mean that you'll have to remove and add lines on the fly. In the last version of mu-template template expansion engine, the expansion is done in-memory)

FYI, my work of mu-template already has this feature: http://code.google.com/p/lh-vim/wiki/muTemplate#Completely_useless_recursive_example

Comment: Yes, I know about muTemplate and I've tried it. But it has some dependencies, I've installed them but didn't work - imho version problems. I didn't have time, not feel like to find the error. I need only a very-very simple "engine" (as you can see above). Thanks!

Comment: The best way to install it is with vim-addon-manager -> mu-template@lh.
Good luck. You'll see, at first the need is simple. Only at first ^^